# Grails check checkbox with value same as variable

Tags: grails

Hi I have this value that I passed to the gsp

```
${d.causalOrganism}
```

I have this three checkboxes and I want one of them to be checked based on the above value. How can I do so? I tried  but doesn't work.

```
<label for="causalOrganism">Causal Organism:</label>

  Fungi<input type="checkbox" value="Fungi" name="causalOrganism" id="causalOrganism1" onclick="checkOrganism(this.id)"/>
  Bacteria<input type="checkbox" value="Bacteria" name="causalOrganism" id="causalOrganism2" onclick="checkOrganism(this.id)"/>
  Virus<input type="checkbox" value="Virus" name="causalOrganism" id="causalOrganism3" onclick="checkOrganism(this.id)" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `checked` attribute to your checkbox based on your desired condition:

```
...
Fungi<input type="checkbox" value="Fungi" name="causalOrganism" id="causalOrganism1" onclick="checkOrganism(this.id)" ${(d.causalOrganism == 'causalOrganism1') ? "checked='checked'" : ''}/>
...
```

You should think about using the grails [checkBox](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/checkBox.html). With this you could use the `checked` attribute directly.

Comment: It would be `${(d.causalOrganism == 'Fungi') ? "checked='checked'" : ''}`